# Doc2vec most similar document to a query string

Tags: word2vec, similarity, nlp, information-retrieval, similar-documents

I'm working on a project and I created doc2vec representation of different academics which include their patents and publications etc. For each publication and patent I have information such as title and abstract. Now, I want to do a search on all of the professors and find which professor is the most similar to a query string, such as "deep learning" or "computer networking". I have tried to use the infer_vector() to create a doc2vec representation of the query string using the already generated model and calculate the cosine similarity between the vectors. But I got terrible results. For example, when I search for "computer networking", it will give me the result of professor from History. 
Is there any recommendation of how to find most similar document to a query string?

Comment: Welcome to this site! An easy-to-check alternative would be to use Euclidean distance instead of cosine similarity.

Comment: Hm, I tried the euclidean distance, but it gave me similar results to the cosine similarity methods I tried.  Is it possible that my query string is too short to give good results?

Comment: You can go for an easier-to-pass evaluation  to see how far off is the model. To this end, see if a good result shows up in top 3, 5, 10 closest matches. Also, keywords in a paper are way more important than the abstract according to your queries, place a special emphasis on them.